# Can a position in a configuration space be of negative value?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

According to Goldstein's book, when trying to derive the Lagrange Equation from Hamilton's Principle using a similar example:

$\int_{x1}^{x2} M(x)n(x) dx = 0$

Since n(x) is arbitrary, M(x) must vanish in the interval between x1 and x2. As such, it concludes that M(x) = 0 which leads to the Lagrange Equations. But what if M(x) is an odd function and x1 to x2? Won't the integral also vanish even when M(x) is not of zero value? But to have an odd function, we need to have one of the BC to be at a position of negative configuration space. Right?
So, can a position in a configuration space be of negative value?
Or is there something wrong with my way of looking at the problem?

Comment: An odd function M(x) would not make the integral vanish for **arbitrary** $n(x)$.  Take for instance $x_1=-1$, $x_2=1$, $M(x)=n(x)=x$

Comment: Yes, although $x$ can be negative (for example, in the Cartesian coordinate system, and where the boundaries are at $x=\pm\infty$) it doesn't change that fact that $M(x)$ must be zero when $\eta(x)$ is arbitrary - since $\eta(x)$ is arbitrary, you can always choose it to also be odd, so that the product $M(x) \eta(x)$ is even and the integral is no longer zero (by virtue of solely the argument of the integrand being an odd function, and so we're back to square one: that the integral can be zero *only* when $M(x)$ is zero)

Comment: If you think there is  a problem with negative $x$ (which I don't see why that should be a problem) you could just shift the whole thing and take for instance: $x_1=0$, $x_2=2$, $M(x)=n(x)=x-1$

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326696/question-about-principle-of-least-action-landau/326701#326701)

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the integral of the product must be zero for ***any*** $n(x)$, and this can only be true if $M(x)$ is zero.

Hint: If $M(x)$ is an odd function, will $M(x) n(x)$ be odd for *any* $n(x)$?

Yes, positions is configuration spaces can have negative values. I don't see anything wrong with that.